# Configuring LoraWan Gateway

Tags: iot, gateway, lora

I'm trying to build a LoRaWan Network using a sensor programmable with Arduino and a Dragino Lora Shield, I have found many solutions for using the gateway, including An RPI and another Dragino Lora Shield or with iC880A, and the data I recieve will be sent do a server in the cloud. I am very confused about programming the gateway, do i need to tell it to connect to the node and to the server ? or does it recieve the date automatically ? and do I program the server to connect to the gateway or directly to the nodes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** do i need to tell it to connect to the node? or does it recieve the date automatically ?

You have to configure your gateway and devices either in ABP mode or OTAA mode.

> Over-the-Air Activation (OTAA) Over-the-Air Activation (OTAA) is the
>   preferred and most secure way to connect with The Things Network.
>   Devices perform a join-procedure with the network, during which a
>   dynamic DevAddr is assigned and security keys are negotiated with the
>   device.
>
> Activation by Personalization (ABP) In some cases you might need to
>   hardcode the DevAddr as well as the security keys in the device. This
>   means activating a device by personalization (ABP). This strategy
>   might seem simpler, because you skip the join procedure, but it has
>   some downsides related to security.

**2)** do i need to tell it to connect to the server? and do I program the server to connect to the gateway or directly to the nodes ?

Your server shouldn't talk to the nodes, it only communicates with your LoRaWAN gateway.

There are several ways for a gateway to send data to your server. For example, you could use MQTT or Protocol Buffer.

Answer (score 1):

A gateway in a LoRaWAN does what gateways in general do: mediates communication between heterogeneous media.
A LoRaWAN gateway is essential just a packet forwarder. The specific Network Server to communicate with is, in general, configured in each LoRaWAN gateway.

As a starting point have a look at this implementation:
https://github.com/Lora-net/packet_forwarder

Note: Any LoRaWAN packet received from the gateway's RF module is forwarded to the Network Server and vice versa*. The Network Server handles: end-device authentication, end-device message de/encryption on the session level, end-device duplicated messages, end-device replayed messages, end-device data rate throttling, data/routing exchange with user applications (This is where commercial Networks Server solutions have loads of options), and more...